# WebRequestHandler force use VPN

Tags: c#, http, vpn

I have two networks available on my machine
Network1: My standard with internet access
Network2: A VPN offered by my company (without internet access)

There is no proxy installed. Checked that with several tests.

When using e.g. Firefox connecting to an URL reachable only via Network1 (e.g. google) works.
Connecting to an URL reachable only vie Network2 also works without noticing any difference. Proxy is disabled in connection settings.

But when using WebRequestHandler (or HttpWebRequest) I cannot connect to any machine that is
only reachable via Network2.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'SomeNameOnNetwork2'

There are some answers on stackoverflow that indicate to give a clue but they all suggest about assigning a proxy to the request but there is non available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two subnets with different ranges of IP and different masks.  IP Routing uses two different methods 1) Using the IP address and masks of router and servers a message is routed towards the destination 2) ARP were a machine puts out a request for a router/server that can forward message to destination.  Your machine could have two network cards one for each subnet (mask and IP of card determines subnet) or the subnets could be virtual where ARP determines which subnet is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not software related (in respect to my question) but was more a misconfiguration on IT's side. Don't know any details but now it works as expected